# A state space for river crossing puzzle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, automata

I am solving the river crossing puzzle with 6 participants.
You must transfer all the people across the river in this flash game respecting the following rules:

The ferry can carry no more than 2 people.
Only the Adults (mom, dad and policeman) can operate the ferry.
Dad can not be in the presence of the girls w/out Mom
Mom can not be in the presence of the boys w/out Dad
The thief can not be alone with any of the family w/out the policeman.

We need to create the state space and as I am creating mine I am not sure if I am doing it properly.

In my case I represent the state as A/B where A are the people on the left side and B are the people on the right side. This is what I have so far.
I feel like I will get a lot of states, so I am worried that I am doing something wrong. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: I’d take the state as: Who is on the left side, and where is the boat?